# Jest test: Awating multiple promises in connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, jestjs

I have a connected component (HOC) that fetches some data in `componentDidMount`, like:

```
function setData(data) {
  return { type: "SET_DATA", data: data };
}

function fetchData() {
  return axios.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two");
}

function getData(dispatch) {
  return () => fetchData().then(response => dispatch(setData(response.data)));
}

class Welcome extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.data) {
      return <div>We have data!</div>;
    } else {
      return <div>Waiting for data...</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

Full code can be seen here: https://github.com/gylaz/react-integration-test-example/blob/eb3238c0a8aa4b15331a031d7d2d3a0aa97ef9c7/src/App.js

And my test looks like:

```
it("renders without crashing", async () => {
  axios.get = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({ data: { one: 1, two: 2 } });
  });
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const component = await ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);

  expect(div.textContent).toEqual("We have data!");
});
```

Full test code here: https://github.com/gylaz/react-integration-test-example/blob/eb3238c0a8aa4b15331a031d7d2d3a0aa97ef9c7/src/App.test.js

The test passes fine!

However, when I make a modification to the `fetchData` method to extract out the actual data from the response (via Promise), like:

```
function fetchData() {
  return axios
    .get("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two")
    .then(response => response.data);
}

function getData(dispatch) {
  return () => fetchData().then(data => dispatch(setData(data)));
}
```

The test will fail, until I add another `await` right before the first `await`:

```
it("renders without crashing", async () => {
  axios.get = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({ data: { one: 1, two: 2 } });
  });
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const component = await await ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);

  expect(div.textContent).toEqual("We have data!");
});
```

Here's a PR showing the above: https://github.com/gylaz/react-integration-test-example/pull/1

The more `then`s in my call chain, the more `awaits` I need to add, and that seems cumbersome.

Is there a better way to await everything at once in the test, or another solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best thing I found instead of multiple `await`s is to wrap the expectation in `setImmediate` or `process.nextTick`. And you don't need to use `async/await`.

For example:

```
it("renders without crashing", () => {
  axios.get = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({ data: { one: 1, two: 2 } });
  });
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const component = ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);

  setImmediate(() => {
    expect(div.textContent).toEqual("We have data!");
  });
});
```

An explanation about promises and the event look can be found in [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules).

One downside of this approach is that Jest will crash the test runner if an expectation fails (rather than showing the failure but not crashing). There is currently a bug which can be followed in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2059).